# WPF Expander won't expand left when inside Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expander

I have a grid with 4 columns. In the first column is a Canvas with a ZIndex of 99 and inside that is an expander. The expand direction is set to RIGHT. When I click on the header, the expander expands OVER TOP of column 2...which is exactly what I want.  I'm trying to replicate this (only the opposite direction) inside column 4, so that when expanded, it will show over column 3. Even though I've marked the ExpandDirection of the second expander to "Left", it still expands to the right, and off the screen.

**Here is the working expander:**

```
<Canvas Grid.Column="0" Panel.ZIndex="99" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5"> 
    <Expander ExpandDirection="Right" Style="{DynamicResource OptionsExpanderStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,2,0">
            <Grid Background="White">

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Expander>
</Canvas>
```

**Here is the broken expander:**

```
<Canvas x:Name="rightCanvas" Panel.ZIndex="99" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,5">
    <Expander ExpandDirection="Left" Style="{DynamicResource OptionsExpanderStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,0,0,0">
            <Grid Background="White" Width="150">

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Expander>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet, it was the only way I found that allowed me to expand OVER the rest of the controls that are in columns 2 and 3. Any other ways to do this? Simply putting the ZIndex high on the expander doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use canvas.

Try something like that:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Background="LightBlue"
            TextAlignment="Center" Text="Left Column"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Background="LightCoral" 
            TextAlignment="Center" Text="Right Column"/>
    </Grid>
    <Expander Background="LightGray" ExpandDirection="Right"
        Header="LeftMenu" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <StackPanel Width="200">
            <TextBlock Text="Some menu stuff"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Some more"/>
        </StackPanel>   
    </Expander>
    <Expander Background="LightGray" ExpandDirection="Left"
        Header="RightMenu" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <StackPanel Width="200" >
            <TextBlock Text="Some menu stuff"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Some more"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I agree. Expander expands correctly but moves itself within the parent->the canvas.

Comment: You really should get rid of all those canvas :D

Comment: Can someone explain why I shouldn't use canvas (aside from the fact that it's not working for me). I'm in the process of implementing the answer above, but I'm just curious why people are saying I shouldn't use the canvas.

Comment: People coming from `WinForms` or other absolute positioning UI frameworks love canvas and use it a lot. It leads to incomprehension and layout nightmares most of the time. Canvas should be used scarcely, when you really need this absolute positioning feature. Most often than not, there's a nice way to avoid it.

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet, thanks for the answers. Yeah, I never use Canvas, but it worked in this situation (or, at least, half worked). Your solution is better though. Thanks!

Comment: @Nicolas Repiquet : i have the same problem,and this is a good solution,but in this way ,how can i put the expander in a specific place,like a column of the grid?