# WPF Expander won't expand Up when is inside Canvas?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, expander

i have an expander that located in a canvas and want to expand it up,but it's togglebutton move to down when it opens.whats the problem,this is my code:

```
  <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="99"  Width="20" Height="20" >
            <Expander
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                ExpandDirection="Up">
                <Grid>
                    <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="hhhh" Height="200" ></Button>
                </Grid>
            </Expander>
        </Canvas>
```

Comment: See [Expander won't expand left when inside Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10300139/620360) too.

Comment: @ LPL:thanks but i had seen before,it's not what i need.

Answer (score -1):

Change `ExpandDirection` to `Down` so the stuff you want to appear will appear below the expander button, rather than above it.

Comment: @ Dave : thanks but i want to the stuff appear above the expander button!